# Microsoft patching folders

Tags: security, windows-update, patch-management, dll

After extracting a Microsoft security patch, I got several folders containing the updated DLL. For Windows XP SP3 I have two folders: SP3GDR and SPQFE. Does anyone know what is the difference between those two folders? also what does 'GDR' and 'QFE' mean?

The two DLLs have a different MD5 signature.

Answer (score 4):

GDR stands for General Distribution Release.
QFE stands for Quick Fix Engineering.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/gauravagg/archive/2007/04/27/jargons-gdr-and-qfe-release.aspx).